# ThumbnailPhoto from ActiveDirectory returned wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, active-directory, ldapjs

I first want to mention that I'm not an expert with LDAP.

What I need is to get from my company's ldap some information including the user photo.
My problem is that after I get all the information I need, the `thumbnailPhoto`
appears to be somehow corrupted. I'll show an example:
`\ufffdPNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0000\ufffd\u0000\u0000\u0000\u ...`

I first noticed this when I tried to apply it on my front end client and couldn't make an image from the returning Buffer. Plus when I checked in LDAP to see the photo size of the returned one is almost double in size.

I checked to see if there was a problem with way the photo was saved in LDAP, copy pasted into a converter and all was fine.

I'll give a code snippet of how I get info from LDAP with a library called [activedirectory](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory):

```
const ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');

exports = module.exports = () => {

return {
    auth: (doc) => {
        let user = 'project@ad.company.com',
            passwd = 'password provided by IT team';

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let ad = new ActiveDirectory({
                url: 'ldap://something.ad.company.com:389',
                baseDN: 'OU=Company,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com',
                username: user,
                password: passwd,
                attributes: { user: [] }
            });

            ad.authenticate(doc.username, doc.password, (err, auth) => {
                if(auth){
                    ad.findUser(doc.username, (err, user) => {
                        if(err){
                            reject(err);
                        } else {
                            resolve(user);
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    reject(err);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

}

exports['@singleton'] = true;
```

I've been struggling with this for some time but I don't understand what happens. The only information I have about this is at this [link](https://github.com/joyent/node-ldapjs/issues/137) which tells that "ldapjs does not know that the thumbnail is really binary" but that was in 2013.

I would appreciate some help, or at least any other methods or libraries I can use in node with express.

At the moment the application uses:

```
"activedirectory": "^0.7.2",

"electrolyte": "0.3.0",

"express": "^4.16.3",
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reviewing again all the issues posted on activedirectory repository I found the answer I needed.

```
  const customeParser = function(entry, raw, callback){ if (raw.hasOwnProperty("thumbnailPhoto")){ entry.thumbnailPhoto = raw.thumbnailPhoto; } callback(entry) }      

  let ad = new ActiveDirectory({
            url: 'ldap://something.ad.company.com:389',
            baseDN: 'OU=Company,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com',
            username: user,
            password: passwd,
            attributes: { user: [] },
            entryParser: customeParser
        });
```

On the front end and if you are using Angular 4+:

```
this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:image/png;base64,'+ new Buffer(thumbnailPhoto).toString('base64'))
```